# Running 64bit dylib with 32bit ruby on Mac

Tags: ruby, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, dynamic-library, ruby-llvm

I was trying to install [ruby-llvm](https://github.com/jvoorhis/ruby-llvm).

I could install llvm with `brew install llvm -shared`, and I also could install `ruby-llvm` with `sudo gem install ruby-llvm` command.

However, when I tried to run the [examples](https://github.com/jvoorhis/ruby-llvm/samples), I got these error messages.

```
/Users/smcho/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ffi-1.1.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:121:in `block in ffi_lib': 
Could not open library '/DIR/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-llvm-3.0.0/lib/libRubyLLVMSupport-3.0.0.dylib': 
dlopen(/DIR/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-llvm-3.0.0/lib/libRubyLLVMSupport-3.0.0.dylib, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
/DIR/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-llvm-3.0.0/lib/libRubyLLVMSupport-3.0.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I checked that the dynamic library is 64bit.

```
file /DIR/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-llvm-3.0.0/lib/libRubyLLVMSupport-3.0.0.dylib 
libRubyLLVMSupport-3.0.0.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

And it seems that ruby is running in 32bit mode. `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i386-darwin11.4.0]`.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there a way to download 32bit version of `ruby-llvm` or 64bit version of `ruby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've installed ruby in 32 bit mode. Would installing ruby in 64 bit mode solve the problem?

To force 64 bit you could try the following with a recent version of RVM:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --64
```

or
    $ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-arch=x86_64

(from: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2012/rvm-stable-and-more/)

For compiling 32 bit mode ruby on OS X we have --32, --64 and --universal flags:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --universal # to build fat binary including both 32 and 64 bit binaries
$ rvm install 1.8.7 --32 # to build only 32 bit ruby
$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-arch=i386 # is equivalent to the 32 bit one, but is available only via RVM, ruby 1.8.7 sources do not support it.
```